# Deny delete of an S3 bucket if a specific tag exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to building a policy to deny deletion of an S3 Bucket if a specific tag exists.
My idea is, if an S3 bucket has the tag (for example):

Key: **prevent_delete**
Value: **true**

and someone is try to delete the bucket, deny that permission.so far this is the policy i've been testing:

```
{
            "Sid": "VisualEditor3",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "s3:DeleteBucket",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/prevent_delete": "true"
                }
            }
        }
```

but still allow to delete S3 bucket even if exist the tag on the S3 Bucket.
I wonder if AWS support this action defined by specific tag.
In that case, could anyone help me how to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, its not possible. IAM policies based on tags are only supported for **objects**, not buckets. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-services-that-work-with-iam.html):

> Amazon S3 supports tag-based authorization for **only object resources**.

You would have to re-write your policy to only deal with objects, not the bucket itself.